# How to get LSP like formatting in Org Mode?

Tags: org-mode, lsp

Here is a scenario I use constantly in Rust development:

```
LSP is always on.
I call the LSP feature "format current buffer" (or whatever it's called).
The LSP returns the buffer formatted (internally, the LSP uses `rustfmt`).
```

I know there is no LSP implementation for Org Mode, but maybe it is still possible to achieve this? E.g., I wanna press some button and have the Org Mode syntax formatted. For example: add an empty line after each heading, remove redundant spaces between heading stars and the text, underline in red if there is a syntax error in a header of a block, etc.

P.S. Emacs newbie here, transitioning from Neovim.